# What's this NoSuchMethod exception using Retrofit with Observables?

Tags: android, reactive-programming, observable, retrofit, rx-java

I want to document this answer here to resolve confusion for others who run into the same problem I did. Using v0.18 of rxjava-core and rxjava-android, any time I attempt to return an Observable from a Retrofit call, I get the following NoSuchMethod exception.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: rx.schedulers.Schedulers.executor

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Retrofit 1.5.1.

From its [change log](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-151-2014-05-08), emphasis added.

> ### Version 1.5.1 (2014-05-08)
>
> - New: @PartMap annotation accepts a Map of key/value pairs for multi-part.
> - Fix: MockRestAdpater uses the ErrorHandler from its parent RestAdapter.
> - **Experimental RxJava support updated for v0.18** and is now lazily initialized.

Comment: Thanks, Jake. I had my Retrofit library pinned to 1.4.+ in Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Version 0.18 of RxJava deprecated and eliminated Schedulers.executor. The RxJava team decided there were too many problems supporting this scheduler and maintaining the functional reactive contract of an Observable. It appears that Retrofit relied upon this scheduler to provide Observable results.

There are three options:

1. Use version 0.17 of RxJava for now. You should be aware that the executor scheduler does not fulfill the entire reactive contract of Observables. Read the following bug links for details so you know the weaknesses of the existing implementation:

   https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/issues/711
   https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/issues/713

   There are new scheduler implementations in RxJava that resolve issues the original executor scheduler had. You can either
2. Wait for a new Retrofit to fix this issue or
3. Hot-patch your copy of the library to use another scheduler implementation which may behave differently.

I'll edit my answer and submit a pull request if I can come up with a general purpose patch to Retrofit for this issue. I'm not aware of a good alternative right now. At this point, the issue is being hotly debated by the RxJava authors.

https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/issues/1219